# Error mapping with CSV helper the value of one field is null

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

I have a CSV file in the following format:

```
Name,Email,ClientCode
Ch S,auseremail@gmail.com,20210603241
HJ BA,buseremail@gmail.com,20210603261
```

I am using [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) to read the CSV file. When I debug the code in the local environment, data are properly bound to the model.

But when I deploy the code to the production environment, the value of `ClientCode` is zero or null.

Class I am using:

```
public class ClientEmail
{
    [Name("Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Name("ClientCode")]
    public long ClientCode { get; set; }
    [Name("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ClientEmailMap : ClassMap<ClientEmail>
{
    public ClientEmailMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Name).Name("Name");
        Map(m => m.Email).Name("Email");
        Map(m => m.ClientCode).Name("ClientCode");
    }
}
```

Code that reads the CSV file and binds it to the model:

```cs
var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
{
    NewLine = Environment.NewLine,
    Delimiter = ",",
    HeaderValidated = null,
    MissingFieldFound = null,
    IgnoreBlankLines = false,
    HasHeaderRecord = true
};


string path = Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, $"csv/{fileName}");

var reader = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, $"csv/{fileName}"));


using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
{
        var records = await csv.GetRecordsAsync<ClientEmail>().ToListAsync();
}
```

Here in the records, the value of `ClientCode` is always null. So I changed the property type to `long` from `string`, but again the value is 0.

Comment: 1) Are you saying that it retrieves the correct values for `Name` and `Email`? 2) Also, does it read *all* the lines? 3) Is `Environment.NewLine` what you intend, or should it be `"\r\n"`?

Comment: yeah, it reads all the lines and it reads `Name` and `Email`. but doesn't read `ClientCode`

Comment: Is `Environment.NewLine` == `"\r\n"` in the production environment? E.g., it would not be on Linux or Mac. If there was a trailing `\r` on the number part because CsvHelper was using the wrong NewLine setting, that could make the parsing fail.

Comment: I am using heroku.com to host my application, maybe it is using Linux.

Comment: so i should change my old code to NewLine = "\r\n"?

Comment: The CSV file format is defined in [RFC 4180](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180) to use `"\r\n"` (they call it CRLF), so yes, it would be a good idea to try that. Heroku's [home page](https://www.heroku.com/) says "you can use any language that runs on **Linux** with Heroku via a third-party buildpack," so I guess you are using perhaps the .NET Core buildpack.

Comment: yeah i tried `NewLine = "\r\n"` it is working now. Thank you for guiding me to the right answer. I learned a new thing today. Never thought that could be the reason, after debugging the whole day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specification for CSV files, [RFC 4180](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180), states that

> Each record is located on a separate line, delimited by a line break (CRLF).

Note that CRLF = `"\r\n"`.

If you are using .NET Core, you could run your code on an operating system where the default newline character sequence is just LF, e.g. Linux or Mac, so `Environment.NewLine` would not be the correct NewLine setting, and there would be a CR character on the end of the digits, which could cause parsing them to a number to fail.

The solution is to use `NewLine = "\r\n"` for CSV files which comply with the standard to make sure your code works everywhere.